# The class changes, but the background will not, why will it not change?

Tags: jquery, css

Im sure this is simply and i am missing something obvious, but I am trying to create it so that the background toggles between a highlight and the default color. I can get the background to change is if I do:

`.css("background-color", "yellow")`

But trying to toggle the class for some reason does not work. It changes the class on the `.black` but that's all, no background color change.

```
//This is my JQuery statement
Home.HighlightBackground = function ()
{
    $(".black").click(function()
    {
        $(this).toggleClass("highlighted")
    })

}


//This is the JQuery that creates the board

var cells = $(".cell");
var colorCount = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
{
    var cell = $(cells[i]);
    var isDark = colorCount % 2 == 0;
    var isNextRow = (i + 1) % 8 == 0;
    colorCount += isNextRow ? 2 : 1;
    cell.css("background-color", isDark ? "navy" : "white");
}


//This is the related CSS

.home > .board
{
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.home > .board > .row
{
    display: table;
}

.home > .board > .row > .cell
{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}

.piece
{
    background-size: 75px 75px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-origin: content-box;
}

.red
{
    background-image: URL('../images/red.png');
}


.black
{
    background-image: URL('../images/black.png');
}

.highlighted
{
    background-color: yellow;  
}


//html source



<html>

<head>
    <title>@Model.PageTitle</title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Home.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

        <script         src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-    ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/Home.js"></script>

        <div class="home">

            <div class="board">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                    <div class="cell"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                    <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Post some `html` too for this to preview!!

Comment: Have you checked the generated html source with Firebug?

Comment: I don't doubt you have reasons but just think about switching everything to "background-color". I guess, "black.png" is a black pixel? If so, change to color to avoid overload and improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `background` property instead of your individual background properties. `background` will overrule any previously declared `background-color` and `background-image` among other `background-*` declarations to the element.

CSS

```
.black {
  background: URL('../images/black.png');
}

.highlighted {
  background: yellow;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/x2o0hckq/)

Answer (score 0):

You mix `background-image` and `background-color`. If this is an option, set both to `background` to get the background set yellow. Otherwise the image will always be rendered above the color.

Another approach could be overriding the `background-image` property in the highlighted-class:

```
.highlighted
{
    background-color: yellow;
    background-image: none;
}
```

Comment: Added the html source at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are mixing `background-color` with `background-image`. The image attribute has priority, so the image will overlay the color.
If that is the problem, you can do something to change this:

1 - Change css hightlight to:

```
    .highlighted
        {
            background-image:none;
            background-color: yellow;  
        }
```

2 - OR Create new css class to mix of .highlighted and .black, eg:

```
    .black.highlighted
        {
            background-image:none;
        }
```